# Creating a multi-select in Jade/Pug

Tags: node.js, express, pug, multi-select

thanks in advance for any help / thoughts you can provide.

How can I create a multi-select dropdown in Jade/Pug?

Here's what I've tried:

```
    span Skills
    #output
    form(method='get')
      select.chosen-select(data-placeholder='Choose tags ...' name='tags[]' multiple='')
        each skill in Skills
          option=skill
```

This allows me to create a menu of items, but none can be clicked or selected.

[image]

I've been using this code as my guide, as this is exactly what I want to create. It uses *chosen*, which I've tried downloading and linking to in the script, but also cannot seem to get working.

[image]

Any help is very much appreciated - even if it's a much simpler way to accomplish this same goal, without using chosen.

Comment: Pug is a way of generating HTML. Before you give up on it, use View Source... to examine the HTML it generates; maybe you can spot your error.

Comment: Your code is fine, it's probably something to do with `chosen-select` from that other library you're using alongside pug.  Try removing the extra elements from the select object until it works.